# Implementing fall damage phaser.js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So i'm trying to make some fall damage, with the implementation of seeing whether the player is on the floor or not, but i'm encountering an issue in my if statement

```js
console.log(this.player.body.velocity.y) // works
    this.fallDmgAmt = 0;
    if(this.player.body.onFloor()==false && this.player.velocity.y >= 300){ // doesn't work
      console.log("falling") 
      
    }
```

the first velocity works but the second doesn't, any explanations?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the if statement to the following:

```
if (this.player.body.onFloor() == false && this.player.body.velocity.y >= 300) {
    console.log("falling");
}
```

You are using `this.player.velocity.y` instead of `this.player.body.velocity.y`.